# Any free PDF or chart generators for ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, charts, generator

What are the best free PDF and chart generators for ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PDF:

- [PDFjet Open Source Edition](http://pdfjet.com/os/edition.html)
- [Sharppdf](http://sharppdf.sourceforge.net/)

For Charts:
[

- [Open Flash Chart](http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2007/11/Open-Flash-Chart-for-ASPNET---SubSonic.aspx)
- [dHTMLx Char](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxChart/index.shtml)t (It is to
  recommend!)

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in creating a chart, putting it on an ASP.NET webform, and allowing a user to view it as PDF, for free, it's hard to beat [SQL Reporting Services ReportViewer controls.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345248.aspx)

You can use Visual Studio to design the charts, put them in .rdlc files, then host those .rdlc files in a ReportViewer control. The report is initially rendered as HTML, but you can allow a user to export these as PDF, CSV, Excel, or other formats.

If you only want to create charts you can also use the [ASP.NET Charting Controls](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/07/built-in-charting-controls-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx), which require a bit more work but produce some impressive results.